# How can I put multiple browse components in a codenameone container?

Tags: codenameone

I will like to put multiple browser components in a form/container and have each displaying different html pages. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes. Recommended, no.

The problem is that native widgets handle their own scrolling so the experience will be sub-par. They can't perform as well as our builtin widgets either. You will get a sub par UX.

Comment: Ok. The nearest widget that I can use is the RichText. but it is quiet limited in what it can render. It cannot for instance display an image. Or is there a better alternative to display simple html page.

Comment: In our Facebook clone we used a combination of rich text and images in a predefined position. The simple `<img>` tag can be easily added to rich text but that's probably not what you want. You probably want `float` which is a bit harder.

Comment: Ill explore the richtextview